# quickest way to update a Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, utf8-decode

Just wondering what the best way to update an entire (large) database would be.

Bascially I have inherited a DB which had character issues, with some help I have sorted the character issues going forward (being written in) however the existing data needs cleaning up.

There was a good suggestion that I could use utf_decode to clean all this up - I have tried this on a wrong value in the page itself (when pulled in) and it works great.

As there seems to be a lot of tables, and alot of data, what's the best / quickest way to sweep all the data in the entire DB by using utf_decode ?

Thanks

Thanks for the comments, I can't seem to comment directly so dropping as message in here - I will have a look through and give them a go ! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch all the data, convert it and insert it as:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (id, text)
(1, 'utf8'), (2, 'utf8'), (3, 'utf8')
```

etc.

Goes faster then to do a php loop with multi INSERT queries.

**EDIT:**

If you use a nice array, you could run a smooth system to do this:

```
$arr = array('users' => array('user_id', 'text', 'username', 'first_name')));

foreach(array_keys($arr) as $h) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$h}");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
        // Loop thingies, utf8_decode then and stuff
    }
    // Then implode them nicely and use above query
}
```

Tell me if you need more code example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the MySQL function CONVERT? Depending on your data, you may be able to update tables in a single statement, such as "UPDATE mytable SET myfield = CONVERT(myfield USING utf8)".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html